# SUMming column values based on String ID and set result to a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

The question might seen repeated, but I've looked for a solution before posting it and I couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to perform a SUM of column values based on a string passed by the user, but I think I'm doing it wrong on my **MainActivity.java** or on my **DatabaseAccess.java** because my app crashs when the string is passed.

Here is my DatabaseAccess.java method:

```
public String SumMoneyValues (String id){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + valueColumn + ") as Total FROM " + tableName + " where " + idColumn + " like ?", new String [] { "%" + id + "%" }, null);
    String total = "";
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        total = String.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Total")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return total;
}
```

I'm using an external database with 5 TEXT columns and 1 DOUBLE column (valueColumn).
On my MainActivity, I've set a TextView and initialized it. Here is my database columns:

```
private static String idColumn = "tag_id";
private static String firstnameColumn = "first_name";
private static String lastnameColumn = "last_name";
private static String phoneColumn = "phone";
private static String addressColumn = "address";
private static String emailColumn = "email";
private static String valueColumn = "valor";
```

By the way, my search method is working fine:

```
public List<Contact> getTagDataById(String id) {
    List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + tableName + " where " + idColumn + " like ?", new String[] { "%" + id + "%" });
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(0));
        contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
        contact.setTagId(cursor.getString(4));
        contact.setValor(cursor.getString(5));
        list.add(contact);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to implement on my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initData();
    initView();
    initClick();

    // Find the GUI components
    this.databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());}

private String SumMoneyValues (String str) {
    databaseAccess.open();
    String soma = databaseAccess.SumMoneyValues(str);
    databaseAccess.close();
    return soma;
}

private void initView() { 
    swTotalSum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.swTotalSum);
    initListView();
}

...

String testeSoma = SumMoneyValues(epctag);
    if (testeSoma != null){
        swTotalSum.setText(testeSoma);
    } else{
        epcTTS.speak("Something went wrong!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

What is the code to call the **SumMoneyValues** method on my MainActivity? Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: **1** - You don't need to loop your cursor, since you'll get a single value from the SUM function. **2** - Try this `total = String.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(0));`

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: @Fantômas I'll try ir now. What about the MainActivity code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @forpas How do I do that? I'm sorry, totally newbie. The app builds just fine, but it crashs when the action is about to perform.

Comment: @Fantômas still crashing.

Comment: To debug and get the stacktrace see [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug). *P.S. using `LIKE '%1%'` would find rows with id's 1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ....... (i.e. any id that includes 1) and so on.

Comment: `What about the MainActivity code?` **which one**? you didn't post any. How are we supposed to guess the logic you implemented?

Comment: @Fantômas I've just updated with my MainActivity information. The app is not crashing anymore! It looks like it is simply not executing the fetch commands.

Comment: Where are you calling `SumMoneyValues()`?! You have to call it, somewhere, or it won't be executed at all.

Comment: @Fantômas I'm calling it inside of a method which gets the string "epctag".

Comment: Since it is a ***relevant*** bit of code, you should show it.

Comment: @Fantômas nvm, I've just figured it out! Thanks for your help! 
The admins can close the thread! ;-)

Comment: @Fantômas hahahahah... Totally agreed! By forcing me to look at my entire code, you've just made me debug it line by line which, by the way, led me to the solution. Thanks again for that! ;-)